# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to resolve this error.

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - zipUpTest/1051687701.jpg

The following is the source code.

```
        Zip::File.open_buffer(obj) do |zip|

          zip.each do |entry|
            ext = File.extname(entry.name)
            file_name = File.basename(entry.name)

            next if ext.blank? || file_name.count(".") > 1

            dir = File.join(dir_name, File.dirname(entry.name))

            FileUtils.mkpath(dir.to_s)

            zip.extract(entry, entry.name) {true}

            file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
            file_new_name = "#{dir_name}/#{file_name}"

            File.rename(entry.name, file_new_name)

            @input_dir << file_new_name
          end
        end
      end
      Zip::OutputStream.open(zip_file.path) do |zip_data|
        @input_dir.each do |file|
          zip_data.put_next_entry(file)
          zip_data.write(File.read(file.to_s))
        end
      end
```

That means there is no file, how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Check the path and try again? Try using the full path?

Comment: What line does that exception happen on?

Comment: @tadman
`zip.extract(entry, entry.name) {true}`
There is an exception in this part.
I'm not sure how to specify the file path in detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure the file `zipUpTest/1051687701.jpg` exists relative to where the process was run, not where the program is saved.

For example, let's say your program is `/home/taizo/program`. If you're in `/home/taizo` and run `ruby program` then it will look for  `/home/taizo/zipUpTest/1051687701.jpg`. If you're in `/tmp` and run `ruby /home/taizo/program` the program will look for `/tmp/zipUpTest/1051687701.jpg`.

Comment: I see, that means you need to specify the file path explicitly. By the way, it now works in this source code.
**entry.name → dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv"**
`zip.extract(entry, dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv") {true}`
`File.rename(dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv", new_file_name)`

Comment: @taizo `dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv"` is just `dir + ".txt"`.

Comment: It seems I was writing useless code. Thanks you for your advice.